# Xamarin Forms / Mobile Blazor Bindings - Images not displaying in iOS app, but fine in Android app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, blazor

## The Problem

I have a simple sample app using Mobile Blazor Bindings, but I am getting inconsistent behaviour between the Android and the iOS version when it comes to display a simple image (.png).

### Android App

Sample image shows as expected in the Android version of the app.

[image: Page in Android App]

### iOS App

Same sample image does not display in iOS version of the app.
[image: Page in iOS App]

## The Test Image page

The razor page consists only of 2 HTML lines (no C# code).

```
<h3>Test Image</h3>

<img src="Images/Image.png" style="max-width: 100%;"/>
```

The image file `Image.png` is located within the Blazor project, within `wwwroot\Images`

[image: Image file in VS Project]

And the image file is set to "Copy always" to the Output Directory:

[image]

Can anyone offer any advice on what is going on?

Many thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Could you please test by this (/Images/) <img src="/Images/Image.png" style="max-width: 100%;"/>

Answer (score 0):

I used to program in Xamarin.Forms (but not Blazor), and had similar problem with image name convention.

Try naming the image like this: `image@3x.png`, and see if it will be shown?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the images folder in the resources folder at the iOS project, is important to keep the same folder structure you have in the blazor application.

In the iOS project you should have, something like this.

**Resources\wwwroot**\[yourimagefolder]\[yourimage.png]

[image]